# Why would Razor View Engine have incorrect search locations

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Totally bizarre behavior today when working on a VB.NET MVC app. I added a partial to a view and got this. Has anyone seen this before? I ended up just naming the files like this

_SavedSearchesGrid.vbhtml.vbhtml 
SavedProperties.vbhtml.vbhtml

and it worked.. go figure...

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.Partial("_SavedSearchesGrid.vbhtml")
        @Html.Partial("SavedProperties.vbhtml")
    </div>
```

[image: Double Extensions]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't specify `.vbhtml` at the end when your call `Partial`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    @Html.Partial("_SavedSearchesGrid")
    @Html.Partial("SavedProperties")
</div>
```

This is attempting all of the different view engines that have been installed.

Comment: Doh! I can't say I hate vb, but my brain is fried just after a couple of weeks of this stuff, long live C#